# registered sign shows junk in IE browser

Tags: css, html

In my HTML there is a place where i had to include a registered sign. when i include my entity code for it. It shows the sign with no issues in Chrome the same time in IE it shows some 'A' character before the sign i tried different type of codes like

```
-&#174;
-&reg;
```

these code work fine in chrome.

```
<p>&reg;</p>
```

**OutPut:**
**in Chrome:**
    ®

**in explorer:** 
    À®

**in Firefox:**
    À®

i want it just like it is in chrome. for other browsers to.

**Expected OutPut**
**in Chrome:**
    ®

**in explorer:** 
    ®

**in Firefox:**
    ®

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this in the `<head>` of your page:

`<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`